# Cannot Resolve Local DNS Names

Tags: networking

I am using Windows 8.1 on my new laptop. I have a DNS server which is whatever version of bind comes with Mageia Linux 4.1. It is set up and working. I can resolve external names on my Windows 8.1 client, but cannot resolve local DNS names. All my machines are on a workgroup called SMILEY. This workgroup spans multiple subnets. It is working with a Windows XP client, but and with my main1 and main2 servers, but not with my Windows 8.1 machine.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c6630f2f-d609-45dd-9aa1-faced0e34133/cannot-resolve-local-dns-names?forum=MTCWin8 for the answer. In short, it was a router issue.